# How can i select a IE tab from its handle

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I have the Internet Explorer Handle and i have the tab Handle that i want to select.

How can i select this tab?

I know how to select a tab by Index (Using IEAccessible), but i can't get the tabIndex from the handle. The Spy++ doesn't sort them in order.

Comment: You can't.  Tab management is an internal IE implementation detail that isn't exposed in any supported way.

Answer (score 9):

There's a <strike>way</strike> <strike>hack</strike> way  to do it.  Not supported, and dependent upon the version of IE as well as the language of the OS.

In an IE instance, the control with the name "Tab Row" is the
thing that holds all the various tabs. Given an IAccessible
corresponding to that thing, it's easy to enumerate the children,
and get the tabs. An automation app can inspect the URL on each
tab, and then call `IAccessible.accDoDefaultAction(0)`, to activate
a tab by URL.  That's the basic approach.

But I couldn't figure how to directly get the "Tab Row" control
of an IE instance, from a `SHDocVw.WebBrowser` COM object, which is
what an app gets out of `SHDocVw.ShellWindowsClass`.  I tried it a
million ways, and finally the simplest way I could find to get it
to work is this: get the WebBrowser COM object, get the HWND from that
object (which is really the HWND numerous levels "up"), then traverse down the OS HWND hierarchy to find the HWND
with the name "DirectUIHWND".  From there, walk down the IAccessible
tree, to find the "Tab Row", then select the tab and invoke the
method.

It sounds ugly to describe, and it hurt to code it this way. I
could not figure out a way to do the traversal only in HWNDs or
only in IAccessible.  I have no idea why I needed to do both.

---

**In Code**

First, get the HWND of the WebBrowser:

```
        SHDocVw.WebBrowser ietab = ... ?
        string urlOfTabToActivate = ietab.LocationURL;
        IntPtr hwnd = (IntPtr) ietab.HWND;
```

Then get the HWND of the DirectUI thing in the IE instance that controls that WebBrowser:

```
        var directUi = GetDirectUIHWND(hwnd);
```

This is the hacky part. The `GetDirectUIHWND` method is defined like this:

```
    private static IntPtr GetDirectUIHWND(IntPtr ieFrame)
    {
        // try IE 9 first:
        IntPtr intptr = FindWindowEx(ieFrame, IntPtr.Zero, "WorkerW", null);
        if (intptr == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // IE8 and IE7
            intptr = FindWindowEx(ieFrame, IntPtr.Zero, "CommandBarClass", null);
        }
        intptr = FindWindowEx(intptr, IntPtr.Zero, "ReBarWindow32", null);
        intptr = FindWindowEx(intptr, IntPtr.Zero, "TabBandClass", null);
        intptr = FindWindowEx(intptr, IntPtr.Zero, "DirectUIHWND", null);
        return intptr;
    }
```

...where FindWindowEx is a dllimport:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent,
                                              IntPtr hwndChildAfter,
                                              string lpszClass,
                                              string lpszWindow);
```

Then, get the IAccessible for that DirectUI thing:

```
        var iacc = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(directUi);
```

...where, of course, AccessibleObjectFromWindow is a DllImport, with some magic around it:

```
    [DllImport("oleacc.dll")]
    internal static extern int AccessibleObjectFromWindow
        (IntPtr hwnd, uint id, ref Guid iid,
         [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] ref object ppvObject);


    private static IAccessible AccessibleObjectFromWindow(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        Guid guid = new Guid("{618736e0-3c3d-11cf-810c-00aa00389b71}"); // IAccessible
        object obj = null;
        uint id = 0U;
        int num = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd, id, ref guid, ref obj);
        var acc = obj as IAccessible;
        return acc;
    }
```

Ok, then, you walk down the IAccessible tree, to find the "Tab Row". In IE this is the thing that displays all the tabs for the various browser windows.

```
        var tabRow = FindAccessibleDescendant(iacc, "Tab Row");
```

...where that method is:

```
    private static IAccessible FindAccessibleDescendant(IAccessible parent, String strName)
    {
        int c = parent.accChildCount;
        if (c == 0)
            return null;

        var children = AccChildren(parent);

        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            if (child == null) continue;
            if (strName.Equals(child.get_accName(0)))
                return child;

            var x = FindAccessibleDescendant(child, strName);
            if (x!=null) return x;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And...

```
    private static List<IAccessible> AccChildren(IAccessible accessible)
    {
        object[] res = GetAccessibleChildren(accessible);
        var list = new List<IAccessible>();
        if (res == null) return list;

        foreach (object obj in res)
        {
            IAccessible acc = obj as IAccessible;
            if (acc != null) list.Add(acc);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Then, get the IAccessible within THAT, and click it:

```
        var tabs = AccChildren(tabRow);
        int tc = tabs.Count;
        int k = 0;

        // walk through the tabs and tick the chosen one
        foreach (var candidateTab in tabs)
        {
            k++;
            // the last tab is "New Tab", which we don't want
            if (k == tc) continue;

            // the URL on *this* tab
            string localUrl = UrlForTab(candidateTab);

            // same? if so, tick it. This selects the given tab among all
            // the others, if any.
            if (urlOfTabToActivate != null
                && localUrl.Equals(urlOfTabToActivate))
            {
                candidateTab.accDoDefaultAction(0);
                return;
            }
        }
```

....where `UrlForTab` is....

```
    private static string UrlForTab(IAccessible tab)
    {
        try
        {
            var desc = tab.get_accDescription(0);
            if (desc != null)
            {
                if (desc.Contains("\n"))
                {
                    string url = desc.Substring(desc.IndexOf("\n")).Trim();
                    return url;
                }
                else
                {
                    return desc;
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return "??";
    }
```

---

Whew.  I could not find a cleaner, simpler way to do this.

Comment: Great example, thanks a lot.  Could you please also provide example of GetAccessibleChildren method.  It is missing in your example.

Comment: Vlad, GetAccessibleChildren is a Windows API function. The code works perfectly, and it helped me a lot. Actually I ported the code to Delphi. There is a small glitch however: "Tab Row" is localized. As I'm using a French version of IE, I had to change "Tab Row" to "Onglet Ligne". I wonder if there is a way to get this from elsewhere because to cause a big problem fro any IE which is not enagligh version.